# Correct terminology for Python imports

Tags: python, terminology

When I import third-party code in Python, what is the correct terminology to use? For example, in `from collections import Counter`, what do I call `collections` and what do I call `Counter`? Is `collections` a "module"? Then what to call `Counter`?

Comment: Yes, `collections` is a module. `Counter` *happens* to be a class defined in the `collections` module but it could be anything; you imported that, so a new global name has been added to your namespace that is a reference to that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter
```

Here, `collections` is indeed a *module*.

`Counter` is a *name*. It can be a class, or function, or something else. It is simply a named *thing*, and you're bringing that name into your global namespace.

In this particular case, `Counter` is a *class*. We are hinted to this by the fact that it starts with a capital letter. But a look at [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) tells us for certain that it is a class.

So we can say here that we are "importing the `Counter` class from the `collections` module".

Comment: How do you refer to "Counter" then? Do you say, "from the collections *module* I import the *name* Counter?"

Answer (score 0):

`collections` is name of the module and `Counter` is a name of given object that's imported from that module. From english you can guess what's mean `from xxx import yyy`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So you say, from the collections *module* I import the *object* Counter?

Comment: Yes. You're right. BTW SO is not a good place for such questions.

Comment: In Python, everything is an object, so this is technically correct. But as `Counter` is a class, it sounds silly to call it an object

Comment: Ok, where do I ask questions of this kind? On meta?

Comment: Read in a book about programming fundamentals on Python.

Comment: @java-devel: I have three books on basic Python programming here. Neither one addresses this. Maybe I just buy bad books :) Can you recommend one that clarifies the terminology? Regards,

Answer (score 0):

the statement `from collections import Counter` can be interpreted as - *collections* is the module from which you are importing the class, function or variable *Counter*